# remote desktop clients cannot connect after moving collection

Tags: remote-desktop, rdp

so this one has me stumped:
We recently upgraded our RDS server. in the upgrade process we copied our existing RDS Collection virtual disks from our DATA server to the new RDS server. Everything works fine as long as BOTH servers are up. If we shut down the DATA server and reboot RDS then users cannot connect:

[image]

We tried to move the original collection on the DATA server to a "depreciated" folder to test and rebooted the RDS server- again we could not connect; moving the original collection back to the original location on the DATA server and rebooting the RDS server again allows connections.

Keep in mind the session collection being used is on the new RDS server and NOT on the DATA server- we know this as we can mount all of the original virtual disks on the DATA server WHILE someone is logged into the RDS server, so we know that those original Virtual disks are not being mounted.

Not even sure where to start looking - or how to troubleshoot. Any ideas or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Ok SO peeps figured this one out- something happened to our UPD template disk. It is possible that when we moved the user profiles to the new collection that we inadvertently copied the template as well, and this was trying to access the old server. Once we deleted and-re-created the template drive all was right in the world again!